# How to search file over LAN in java?

Tags: java

How to search file in other pc connected through lan in Java?

Comment: Please be more specific. How is your setup? What kind of server, if any, is on the other PC? (ftp, samba, http, dlna?!?! ...) What have you tried so far? Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: What are your options to access the other machine? Is it a windows machine with a shared folder or unix with NFS or FTP or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even try. I would execute a task at the remote node to search locally. You will regret this from both a performance point of view and a reliability point of view. In my experience it is a major mistake for applications to deal with remote file systems in any way whatsoever.

Comment: sorry for that, well, it be windows system connected through LAN. So , what would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: @hussain: 'I would execute a task at the remote node to search locally' ... and organize some TCP/IP communications between them, e.g. HTTP or RMI or Sockets.